# With sum of squared error (SSE), how are larger errors are penalized more than smaller errors?

Tags: error, rms

I read this sentence about the sum of squared error SSE: *"The square ensures the error is always positive and larger errors are penalized more than smaller errors"*. I want to understand what is meant by *"larger errors are penalized more than smaller errors"*, and how to prove that?

Comment: If you square small and bigger values, then the latter will change more then the first one. Plot $x$ vs $x^2$ to convince yourself.

Comment: Consider accepting @Tim answer. If the error is $1$ its square is still $1$, but if the error is $100$ its square is $10000$ which is significantly larger.

Comment: Let an error be $\epsilon$, so that its size is $|\epsilon|$. Then its square can be factored into two terms, $$\epsilon^2 = \omega \times |\epsilon|,$$ with $\omega = |\epsilon|$.  This shows how the square of any number can be considered to be its size multiplied by a *weight* $\omega \ge 0$.  Notice that these weights are directly proportional to the sizes of the errors.  That's all there is to the quotation--it is a mathematical triviality, merely involving a *reinterpretation* of the square of a number.

Comment: *"The sum of squared error"* is not a question. You have to actually ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Plot $x$ against $x^2$. Smaller values squared change less, then larger values squared. The steepness of the slope of $x^2$ increases as $|x|$ grows. So if you square small errors, the penalty is smaller, then if you squared large errors. There is nothing to prove in here, it is just how the square function works.

[image: x vs x^2]